# C# - Using Regex's with TextBox.Validating

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Instead of using if (numberEntered < 1 || numberEntered > 24), is it possible to use a regex to check whether the field is in a 24 hour clock format e.g. 23:00.

```
private void textBox4_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    {
        int numberEntered;

        if (int.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out numberEntered))
        {
            if (numberEntered < 1 || numberEntered > 28)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have to enter a number between 1 and 28");
                textBox4.Text = 5.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need to enter an integer (number)");
            textBox4.Text = 5.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why `5.ToString()` instead of `"5"`?

Comment: @Jonas Elfström Does the same thing...

Comment: @Jonas - I think I can take the blame for the 5.ToString() in part - it comes from an answer I gave. I was in "answer the question at hand" mode rather than "think about the entirety of the code I'm writing" mode, and the question involved treating the text in the textbox as an int - my poor brain fuddled itself :)

Comment: So does `string s = ""+5;` or `Convert.ToString(5)` and that's, kind of, my point. Why do something more complicated than you have to?

Answer (score 2):

```
string time = "23:00";
var time24 = new Regex(@"^(20|21|22|23|[01]\d|\d)(([:][0-5]\d){1,2})$");
bool is24hTime = time24.IsMatch(time);
```

Would probably work but I think that [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes. Is it preferred? No. It is better to parse the string into an integer and validate as you are currently doing then to use a regular expression. Regular expressions weren't really made to do what you are asking them to so the resulting regex would be awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx

Comment: They are more trouble than they are worth, have had some bad exp with them

Answer (score 0):

As Jonas says, using `DateTime.TryParse` is preferable to using a regex, however, you might want to consider using a `DataTimePicker` control.

If you set the `Format` property to `Custom` and then set the `CustomFormat` property to `HH:mm` you will get a textbox like control that restricts input to 24hr time.

Finally, if you set `ShowUpDown` to `true` you will no longer have the calendar visible but have an updown instead.